# Creating Linq from SQL with OrderBy and GroupBy

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following table structure.

```
TableA      TableB          TableC
- MID       - PID           - PID
- NAME      - INIT_DATE     - MID
```

This is the SQL Query that I need to translate into Linq

```
SELECT TOP 10 TableA.NAME, 
               COUNT(TableB.INIT_DATE) AS [TOTALCOUNT]
FROM TableC 
INNER JOIN TableA ON TableC.MID = TableA.MID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableC.PID = TableB.PID
GROUP BY TableA.NAME
ORDER BY [TOTALCOUNT] DESC
```

I tried to reproduce the above query with this Linq query:

```
iqModel = (from tableC in DB.TableC
           join tableA in DB.TableA on tableC.MID equals tableA.MID
           select new { tableC, tableA } into TM
           join tableB in DB.TableB on TM.tableC.PID equals J.PID into TJ
           from D in TJ.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new { TM, D } into MD
           group MD by MD.TM.tableA.NAME into results
           let TOTALCOUNT = results.Select(item=>item.D.INIT_DATE).Count()
           orderby TOTALCOUNT descending
           select new SelectListItem
           {
               Text = results.Key.ToString(),
               Value = TOTALCOUNT.ToString()
            }).Take(10);
```

But I think I am doing something wrong.

The Output of the LINQ and SQL is not same. I think up to JOIN or GROUPBY it is Correct.

**EDIT :-**

**I have also tried the following Linq query but still it's not working correctly.**

```
var iqModel = (from c in DB.TableC
               join a in DB.TableA on c.MID equals a.MID
               join b in DB.b on c.PID equals b.PID into b_join
               from b in b_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new SelectListItem { Text = a.NAME, Value = b.INIT_DATE != null ? b.INIT_DATE.ToString() : string.Empty });

var igModel = iqModel.GroupBy(item => item.Text);

var result = igModel.OrderByDescending(item => item.Select(r => r.Value).Count());
```

I want to understand what am I doing wrong and how can it be fixed.

I am newbie to LINQ to SQL I think in above LINQ I really made it complicated by adding more select.

Comment: No output is not correct. That is the problem. I have Edited my question and put simplified query please check it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the difference is caused by the fact that the SQL `COUNT(field)` function does not include `NULL` values. There is no direct equivalent construct in LINQ, but it could be simulated with `Count(e => e.Field != null)` or like this (which seems to produce better SQL):

```
var query = 
    (from a in db.TableA
     join c in db.TableC on a.MID equals c.MID
     join b in db.TableB on c.PID equals b.PID into joinB
     from b in joinB.DefaultIfEmpty()
     group b by a.Name into g
     let TOTALCOUNT = g.Sum(e => e.INIT_DATE != null ? 1 : 0)
     orderby TOTALCOUNT descending
     select new SelectListItem { Text = g.Key, Value = TOTALCOUNT }
    ).Take(10);
```

which generates the following SQL

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
        [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [Name], 
        1 AS [C2]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Join2].[K1] AS [K1], 
            SUM([Join2].[A1]) AS [A1]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent1].[Name] AS [K1], 
                CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[INIT_DATE] IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [A1]
                FROM   [dbo].[TableAs] AS [Extent1]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[TableCs] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[MID] = [Extent2].[MID]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TableBs] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[PID] = [Extent3].[PID]
            )  AS [Join2]
            GROUP BY [K1]
        )  AS [GroupBy1]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. After using your linq my query is working perfectly. and i also found the mistake that i have done in groupby and orderby.

Comment: Hello Ivan. I found that it is also creating difference because of COUNT and SUM function. can you tell me why? I mean when i use Count function as you said in your answer it's not producing correct query but when i use SUM function it produces correct query. What difference it can cause?

Comment: That's strange, I have no explanation. The two constructs are really equivalent, the only reason I've picked the `Sum` version was because the generated SQL was closer to your original SQL query. The `Count(...)` is a shortcut for `Where(...).Count()` and both produce one and the same SQL. Before posting the answer, I've tried to create a similar model in my EF test environment and the `Sum` and `Count` queries produced one and the same result, but of course this is not a real environment and I don't have your data. Can you give an example of differences you are getting?

Comment: Hello Ivan, Definitely i will put demo over here. Please just give me some time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that you not see "**group by**" command at resulting query, instead of it "**distinct**" command is used. Am I right?

First query makes distinct by TableA.NAME and then calculates COUNT(TableB.INIT_DATE) with the help of subquery like this:

```
select distinct1.Name, (select count() from *join query* where Name = distinct1.Name)
from (select distinct Name from *join query*) as distinct1
```

If so, not worry about it. Because conversion from linq to real t-sql script sometimes very unpredictable (you can not force them to be equal, only when query is very simple), but both queries are equivalent one to another and return same results (compare them to make sure).

Comment: The result will be the same, because in this case LINQ not perform immediately execution of variable's query one by one. LINQ will gather together all queries and executes it as one query when you call ToList() for example and the **result** query will be the same as initial variant, but intermediates, of course, will be another.